# How to sort and join at the same time?

Tags: text-processing, sort, columns, join

I have 2 files, one having 2 columns, another having 1 column.
The second file is sorted using `sort -u`.
Now the task is I need to join this column with the first column of the first file, which is not sorted.

So what will be the syntax? Will `join -j 1 file2.txt sort -s -n -k 1 file1.txt` work?

The output I want is actually the 2nd column of file 2 after joining and the unique entries in it.

File 2

---

```
1
2
3
```

File 1

---

```
2  500
1  5000 
1  300
3  3000 
3  300
4  450
```

Output

---

```
5000
300
500
3000
```

Comment: "Will this work?" Please try it out and check for yourself. I don't understand how your output could have four lines when file 1 only has three.

Comment: Do you need to use `File 2`? Is sorting `File 1` and then removing unwanted entries, e.g., lines with prefix >= 4 || duplicate values out of the question?

Comment: Hello Mat, think like this: The second file is joined against the file 1 on column 1 and then the uniq entries are taken from column 2 of file 1. I tried but I think syntactically its not correct, thats what I was asking if its ok or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need to use non-standard process substitution (`<(...)`) here:

```
sort file1 | join -o1.2 - file2 | uniq
```

Comment: This only works if file2 is already sorted. To really avoid the bashisms, the sorted files would need to be written to a temporary file.

Comment: @jordanm. file2 is sorted according to the OP's question. process substitution is a ksh feature originally, not a bashism. You don't need a temp file, you can use named or /dev/fd/n if supported as ksh/bash/zsh internally do for `<(...)`.

Answer (score 3):

```
join file2.txt <(sort file1.txt) | awk '{print $2}'
```

Answer (score 2):

One way using `sort` + `awk`. I sort the other file by its first number and in stable mode. In `awk` I compare what keys from *file1* match with the keys of *file2* and are not repeated, printing them:

```
sort -snk1,1 file1 | awk '
    FNR == NR { 
        keys[ $1 ] = 1; 
        next; 
    } 
    !values[ $2 ] && keys[ $1 ] { 
        printf "%s\n", $2; 
        values[ $2 ] = 1; 
    }
' file2 -
```

Output:

```
5000
300
500
3000
```